# How to make a view vibrate in an animation in objective-c?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a UIView called qShake. When the user makes an error, I want that view to shake from left to right in a small space for a short period of time. How would I create an animation to do that?

Comment: please clarify your question ? what you are trying to do.

Comment: That code isn't very relevant, it does nothing that resembles an animation. Do you some code from an animation attempt?

Comment: MY UIView is called qShake!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a CABasicAnimation, and set the repeat count to some small value, while animating the position of the view.layer that you want to vibrate.  Note that `clipsToBounds` for the view must be set to NO.  Also be sure to include the QuartzCore framework in the project.

```
- (void)shakeView:(UIView *)view
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    animation.duration = 0.1;
    animation.byValue = @(20);
    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.repeatCount = 10;
    [view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Shake"];
}
```

Comment: Since you are only changing the x value of the position you can animate the @"position.x" property instead. Them you don't have to deal with NSValue. Also, for relative animations (like this) you can use `byValue` instead of `toValue` so that you don't have to add 20 to the current value.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist thanks, that works great, and much cleaner code!